# Replace AuthUserFile with custom PHP script in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, openid

I've been using HTTP authentication through `.htaccess` files every time I've needed quick and dirty password protection for a complete directory (most of the times, in order to hide third-party apps I install for private use). Now I've written some PHP code to replace local passwords with OpenID. That allows me to get rid of HTTP auth in my PHP sites. However, I'm still trying to figure out a trick I can use in non-PHP stuff (from third-party programs to random stuff).

Apache does not seem to support authentication with custom scripts by default (whatever I do, it should work in my hosting provider). That leaves the obvious solution of using `mod_rewrite` to route everything though a PHP script that checks credentials and reads the target file but 1) it looks like a performance killer 2) it will interfere with dynamic stuff, such as other PHP scripts.

I'm wondering whether there's a way to tune up the *router* approach so the script does not need to send the file, or if I'm overlooking some other approach. Any idea?

Comment: This looks like fun, maybe you can get it with your host? http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/

Answer (score 0):

I think your `mod_rewrite` approach would be the only way to do this - but instead of using `readfile()` (as I guess you are, based on what you say about `it will interfere with dynamic stuff, such as other PHP scripts`) you can just `include()` them, so that raw files are written straight to output and PHP code is executed.

Comment: Not straight, they will be mangled through the PHP parser (and even executed if they have PHP inside).

Comment: Apply a filter to the filename to only `include` PHP files, and `readfile` everything else? Seems like a big ask this - since there is no method built in to Apache to deal with custom auth scripts, the *only* option is to force Apache to pass every request through your custom auth script or an Apache module. Writing an Apache module or using `mod_auth_openid` likely conflicts with the requirement of `whatever I do, it should work in my hosting provider`, so the only option you are left with is to pass everything through a custom script.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I've already wasted an absurd amount of time browsing the Apache documentation and it seems that it just can't be done the way I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PHP HTTP-AUTH http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

If OpenID is all what you need consider usage of mod_auth_openid for apache

Comment: Sadly, you can't combine HTTP authentication with custom HTML forms (which is the case for OpenID) because the browser needs to send specific HTTP headers with the username and password.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario While I tend to agree that `you can't combine HTTP authentication with custom HTML forms` there is a little work around to this - although it *relies* on Javascript, which one should never do... but if you really want to, you can create an AJAX request to set the correct HTTP auth details, and these will be carried over to subsequent requests. I'm not recommending it, I'm just pointing out that it *can* be done...